# Using ssh to forward a remote machine's localhost ports

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to run `mysql-workbench` on my local machine, connected to a remote machine via `ssh`. If the remote machine was listening on port 3306, this would be trivial:

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:3306 user@example.com
```

This would allow me to point `mysql-workbench` to `localhost:1234` and all traffic would be routed to `example.com:3306`.

The database on `example.com` however is only listening on `localhost:3306`. Is there a way to forward `example.com:localhost:3306` back through a port to my machine? I have both `nc` and `ncat` available on the local machine, so I think it should be possible to set up a makeshift proxy, I just don't *quite* know how.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is a bit strange and your example should still work because what you're saying is: "when traffic on my local machine is directed at TCP port 1234 send it through this tunnel and **make the machine at the other end** send it to whatever IP address resolves to localhost **on the remote machine** and send it to THAT machine's port 3306. If you had put :remote2.example.com: then the machine you're sshing to would send the packets to whatever remote2.example.com resolved to. For example imagine I have three shells and I have a local machine and a remote machine:

```
[@local  1]$ ssh -L8888:localhost:7777 remote
[@remote 2]$ nc -l -s 127.0.0.1 -p 7777
[@local  3]$ echo 'Hello World!' | nc localhost 8888
```

Will make the `@local  1` shell output "Hello World!". Perhaps the remote service is not really listening on whatever localhost on the remote machine resolves to?

Comment: `nc -l -s 127.0.0.1 -p 7777` complained that `nc: cannot use -s and -l`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on a Red Hat like distro that isn't using netcat-traditional (perhaps you're using nmap-ncat). If you look at the help you'll likely see `-s, --source addr          Specify source address to use (doesn't affect -l)`. You can try `nc -l 127.0.0.1 7777` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your description what is wrong and what you want to do. 
Once you can connect to your server via "trivial" ssh tunnel then you can connect to loopback interface of the remote machine that is localhost:3306.
DB servers are listening on loopback interface by default.
Try connecting to remote machine with explicit loopback IP-address:

`ssh -L 127.0.0.1:1234:127.0.0.1:3306 user@example.com`

It should work without need in netcat and so on. 
If it doesn't then there is something wrong with your database server configuration.