# How can i access service listen on 127.0.0.1 from another computer

Tags: networking, iptables

I have a binary executable which listen on `127.0.0.1:5373`. But I want others can access the service from another computer just like it listen on `0.0.0.0:5373`.

Since it is a binary, I can not modify the source code of it to listen on `0.0.0.0`.

I think `iptables` or `nftables` could do that but not sure how.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1337306

Comment: @Nifle, Not everyone who need the service can ssh to the remote machine

Comment: What is the OS? Do you have root/administrator access?

Answer (score 2):

```
# iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type local -p tcp --dport 5373 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1
```

I'm assuming the programs binds to a tcp port. (If you are unsure, you can use something like `ss -nltpu` to check. Also the story might be more complicated if it's UDP.)

`-m addrtype --dst-type local` is somewhat optional. It only matches traffics that has destination address that is an address of the host itself. This is helpful if the host act as a router or so and you do not want to intercept similar traffics that are for another host.

`-p tcp --dport 5373` is pretty self-explanatory I suppose.

`-j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1` will *also* make sure that *reversed* SNAT will be performed on replying traffics, i.e., the client hosts will see the replies having source address being the "original" destination address. No additional rule needed.

Note that the above rule will only work when `route_localnet` sysctl is set to `1`:

```
# sysctl -w sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet=1
```

(When setting it with persistent conf file, you probably want to set `net.ipv4.conf.default.route_localnet` instead. Please do your own research to find out their difference, if interested.)

Note that effects of both `iptables` and `sysctl` commands are *volatile*. Please do your own research to find out how to make them *persistent* on the distro you use.

P.S. I have no idea whether having `route_localnet` being `1` could pose any security risks btw.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately the service is a UDP service, but I think set `-m udp` and `-p udp` will work? Why it is more complicated?